# Putting a specific Powershell Get-Counter Statistic into a variable

Tags: powershell, monitoring

I'd like to pull a specific statistics from a _Total (the CounterSamples) into a variable, in order to further parse it.

This is what I've tried.
Trying to index with [1] gives error further below. 
Looping didn't seem to get me very far either.

```
cls
$statToCollect = '\Process(_Total)\IO Data Operations/sec'
Get-Counter $statToCollect
Write-Host "================" 
$saveStats = Get-Counter $statToCollect
$ctrSamples = $saveStats[1].CounterSamples
Write-Host "$ctrSamples"
Write-Host "$($saveStats)"
Write-Host "================"

$diskStats = Get-Counter $statToCollect 
$diskStatsLoopCounter = 1 
foreach ($diskStat in $diskStats)
{
    if ($diskStatsLoopCounter -eq 1) 
    {
        write-host "$($diskStat.CounterSamples)" 
    }
    $diskStatsLoopCounter = $diskStatsLoopCounter + 1 
}
```

Results:

```
Timestamp                 CounterSamples                                                     
---------                 --------------                                                     
12/29/2014 9:27:49 AM     \\mpcname\process(_total)\io data operations/sec :                
                          970.6265098029                                                     


================
Unable to index into an object of type Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounter.PerformanceCo
unterSampleSet.
At C:\Users\neal.walters\Documents\DiskUtil.ps1:6 char:26
+ $ctrSamples = $saveStats[ <<<< 1].CounterSamples
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (1:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotIndex


Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounter.PerformanceCounterSampleSet
================
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounter.PerformanceCounterSample
```

Comment: `$saveStats.CounterSamples.CookedValue` seems to be what you need.

Comment: arrays are 0 based in powershell not 1, also you would have to access the index on the Countersamples property instead of the stat collection. For example: `$saveStats.CounterSamples[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PowerShell version 4 on Windows 8.1:

`Get-Counter` returns a `PerformanceCounterSampleSet` and you can access the `CounterSamples` property to get an array of [PerformanceCounterSample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.getcounter.performancecountersample_properties(v=vs.85).aspx) objects.

The particular property that you're interested in is `CookedValue`:

```
$statToCollect = '\Process(_Total)\IO Data Operations/sec'
$total = (Get-Counter $statToCollect).CounterSamples.CookedValue
```

This gets you the result as a double:

```
PS> $total
28.9450419770711

PS> $total.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Double                                   System.ValueType
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  So if you put _Total, it doesn't return a collection?

Comment: By the way, I was on Win 7 with Powershell 2.0, and this ran but returned a null.  I upgrade to Powershell 4.0, which I should have done anyway, and it worked fine.

Comment: No, it was because the `Get-Counter` cmdlet gave only one object. If it had given multiple counters then `$total` would be an array of doubles.

Answer (score 2):

In your particular case `$saveStats` is only the one element.

```
PS C:\Users\mcameron> $saveStats.Count
1
```

Which is why this command would have returned null output as there is not a second.

```
PS C:\Users\mcameron> $saveStats[1]
```

Since there was only the one element either of the following options would have worked for this case.

```
PS C:\Users\mcameron> $saveStats[0]

PS C:\Users\mcameron> $saveStats
```

Also as for the line `Write-Host "$($saveStats)"` since `$saveStats` is an object and not a string it would not expand the way you expect. Pretty sure this occure because the `ToString()` is not overloaded to handle this so just the object type is outputted. Simply having `$saveStats` on its own would allow powershell to format it properly using its own built-in cmdlets.

```
PS C:\Users\mcameron> $saveStats

Timestamp                 CounterSamples                                                                                      
---------                 --------------                                                                                      
12/29/2014 10:56:53 AM    \\c3935\process(_total)\io data operations/sec :                                                    
                          27.7291444862573
```

Similar issue with the line `write-host "$($diskStat.CounterSamples)"` which has the same response as above.

As the other commenters and posters have said you most likely want one of the properties like `CookedValue` which can be easily converted to a string.

```
write-host "$($diskStat.CounterSamples.CookedValue)"
```